# Copy, alt+tab, paste, alt+tab

Tags: autohotkey

I want to do a superpaste and wrote this in AHK. Is my code wrong? I get error on both scripts

Script 1

```
^!c::
Send Send {Ctrl Down}c{Ctrl Up}
Sleep, 100
Send !Tab
Sleep, 100
Send Send {Ctrl Down}v{Ctrl Up}
Sleep, 100
Send Enter
Sleep, 10
Send Enter
Sleep, 100
Send !Tab
Return
```

Script 2

```
^+c::
Send ^c
Sleep, 100
Send !Tab
Sleep, 100
Send ^v
```

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: I pasted the first script in, no error message

Comment: Script 1 nothing happens. Script 2 https://www.dropbox.com/s/2xfilohzjin6ifp/Sk%C3%A4rmdump%202014-07-31%2010.45.58.png

Comment: @user1603548 What should do lines `Send Send {Ctrl Down}c{Ctrl Up}` and `Send Send {Ctrl Down}v{Ctrl Up}` ? What exact keys you want to send with that two lines?

Comment: oups a double "send" my bad.

Comment: what I want it do do: se script 2 it's easier to tell there

Comment: do you guys make script 2 work?

Comment: @user1603548 What keys do you want to send with lines `Send Send {Ctrl Down}c{Ctrl Up}` , `Send Send {Ctrl Down}v{Ctrl Up}` ,  `Send ^c` and `Send ^v`? It is possible to fix your code if you can tell us what exact keys you want to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script 1

```
;SetKeyDelay, 300 ;Sets the delay(Time in milliseconds) that will occur after each keystroke sent by Send and ControlSend. uncomment if something wrong
^+c:: ; ctrl+shift+c
clipboard = ; Empty the clipboard
Send ^c
ClipWait 3 ; Waits 3 sec until the clipboard contains data.
Send !{Tab} ; Switch between the two most recent tasks (is it notepad?)
Sleep, 200
Send {End} ; move to end line
Send {Enter} ; new line
Send {Enter} ; new line separator
Send ^v
Sleep, 200
Send !{Tab} ; Switch between the two most recent tasks (moving back)
```

ctrl+shift+c to activate.

Comment: worked (deleted the {End} thing).